# Error while creating an account

Tags: cleos, nodeos

I got that error while creating an account, anyone knows what's wrong?
[Here](https://youtu.be/vGB37jJfwAg?hd=1) is a recording of what happened now; after enter, I get no output, I need to press Ctrl+C to exit :

````
> ~$ cleos create account creator damian2 name damian11 OwnerKey
> EOS6BvXtPVJeH9HVvv2LfFM7X4fNFZYEhgQgWSrD1JfWcUHSeq5aq ERROR:
> ExtrasError: [OwnerKey
> EOS6BvXtPVJeH9HVvv2LfFM7X4fNFZYEhgQgWSrD1JfWcUHSeq5aq] Create an
> account, buy ram, stake for bandwidth for the account Usage: cleos
> create account [OPTIONS] creator name OwnerKey [ActiveKey]
> 
> Positionals:   creator TEXT                The name of the account
> creating the new account (required)   name TEXT                   The
> name of the new account (required)   OwnerKey TEXT               The
> owner public key for the new account (required)   ActiveKey TEXT      
> The active public key for the new account
> 
> Options:   -h,--help                   Print this help message and
> exit   -x,--expiration             set the time in seconds before a
> transaction expires, defaults to 30s   -f,--force-unique          
> force the transaction to be unique. this will consume extra bandwidth
> and remove any protections against accidently issuing the same
> transaction multiple times   -s,--skip-sign              Specify if
> unlocked wallet keys should be used to sign transaction   -j,--json   
> print result as json   -d,--dont-broadcast         don't broadcast
> transaction to the network (just print to stdout)   --return-packed   
> used in conjunction with --dont-broadcast to get the packed
> transaction   -r,--ref-block TEXT         set the reference block num
> or block id used for TAPOS (Transaction as Proof-of-Stake)  
> -p,--permission TEXT ...    An account and permission level to authorize, as in 'account@permission'   --max-cpu-usage-ms UINT    
> set an upper limit on the milliseconds of cpu usage budget, for the
> execution of the transaction (defaults to 0 which means no limit)  
> --max-net-usage UINT        set an upper limit on the net usage budget, in bytes, for the transaction (defaults to 0 which means no
> limit)
> 
> ```
````

Comment: try `cleos create account damian2 damian11 EOS6BvXtPVJeH9HVvv2LfFM7X4fNFZYEhgQgWSrD1JfWcUHSeq5aq` if `damian2` exists

Comment: Now I've got that error: damianjnc@Damian-PC:~$ cleos wallet unlock -n damian2
password: Unlocked: damian2
damianjnc@Damian-PC:~$ cleos create account damian2 damian11 EOS6BvXtPVJeH9HVvv2LfFM7X4fNFZYEhgQgWSrD1JfWcUHSeq5aq
Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations
Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked.
damianjnc@Damian-PC:~$

Comment: yeah you need to import the private key for damian2 in your wallet  if you haven't

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: I think I already did it:                      damianjnc@Damian-PC:~$ cleos wallet keys
[
  "EOS6BvXtPVJeH9HVvv2LfFM7X4fNFZYEhgQgWSrD1JfWcUHSeq5aq",
  "EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV",
  "EOS6amkkh5BZ6imcTAPCGPLKEpgvAD9FQjkEoYvo8FYippNcKrnax"
]
damianjnc@Damian-PC:~$

Comment: can't tell without knowing the key associated with `damian2` but i'm not sure the account has actually been created. perhaps take a look at [the documentation](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/accounts-1) for creating accounts

Comment: http://youtu.be/vGB37jJfwAg?hd=1 That's what happened now, after enter, I get no output, i need to press ctr+c to exit

Comment: Did you import your account inside your wallet? as @confused00 said make sure your account exit?